# Couldn't import package when I download it using pip download <name_of_package> ? It went to Lib and I am unable to import it

Tags: pip, lib

I am just learning coding

I wanted to download a package from pypi.org using the **pip** function . but after I downloaded it , I wasn't able to import the openpyxl package . I checked where the openpyxl file was that I had downloaded and found the it was in **lib\site-packages** directory instead of being in a **sit-packages** which is a different directory.

*In the picture if have taken pictures of all the visible information that I could find out about this problem and put it one picture, I hope you can understand what my question is by the image .

*Also should i be worried about the red color text that is showing in my terminal .

please if you can help , that would be great , I use windows 10 with python 3.10.

[image: the problems i am facing i put into one image]

I have taken multiple pictures of messages that I could see then put them all in one picture using photoshop , that is why the picture might look inaccurate , I just wanted all the information to be in one picture , hope you can understand my question, and i would be great full if you could help .

Comment: I have taken multiple pictures of messages that I could see then put them all in one picture using photoshop , that is why the picture might look inaccurate , I just wanted all the information to be in one picture , hope you can understand my question, and i would be great full if you could help .

Comment: Please always use the [edit] button under your question to add new or additional information.

Comment: Does it work when you go (in Pycharm) to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Project** -> **Python Interpreter**, then hit the small plus button, search for `openpyxl` and hit **Install Package**?

Comment: HI FlyingTeller , yes this worked . I didn't know such a think existed , thankyou soo much.

Comment: I will post it as an answer then. You can mark it as accepted to let others know what fixed your issue

Answer (score 0):

You have installed `openpyxl` to your global python, but your project in python is using a virtual environment that has its own set of packages. To install into the environment used by your project go (in Pycharm) to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Project** -> **Python Interpreter**, then hit the small plus button, search for `openpyxl` and hit **Install Package**